# How should we handle suggested edits to accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, accepted-answer

I'm not even sure if this link will work, but I was perusing the Suggested Edits queue on SE and came to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/3419476?&_suid=138514479581607093653027437612

Now, it **seems** logical that the person could have fixed the answer.  However, since it was accepted then it is assumed that the original answer provided was sufficient and answered the OP's question.

I skipped it, because I'm not going to go accepting changes to accepted answers.  I mean, what if the new answer is wrong?  I can't ask the OP to test the suggested edit, so how will I know if it will work?

What's the proper course of action here?

Comment: Why should edits to accepted answers **not** be allowed?

Comment: Changed the subject as that's not really what I meant.  I meant more on the lines of, how would we know if suggested changes to code answers would still work for the OP?  It looks like that edit was rejected, should I just assume that's the proper thing to do?

Comment: Downvotes for disagreement on _questions_ (at least) really are a disaster ....

Answer (score 7):

Why should edits to accepted answers **not** be allowed?

The edit in question was correctly rejected (it should have been another answer, perhaps, or a comment informing the author of the different response on Windows). But that stands entirely independent of the status of the post.

Question askers can accept answers for all sorts of reasons, not least answers with spelling mistakes, bad grammar and broken links. Not allowing edits to accepted answers would prevent us from improving their quality. Answers are not just there for the original question asker, after all!